# Adding timestamp to MapView Annotation via Parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, time, parse-platform

This is my current query setup to retrieve data from parse and set it to the annotation pin on mapView. I would like to take the time created also and add a simple `5:00PM` for example within the annotation as well. Is there a way to pull just the time and not the date from parse through my query and set it to the `MKAnnotation`?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
var annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: MapViewLocationManager.location)
//annotationQuery.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint: currentLoc, withinMiles: 10)
annotationQuery.whereKeyExists("Location")
annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (points, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        println("Successful query for annotations")
        // Do something with the found objects

        let myPosts = points as! [PFObject]

        for post in myPosts {
            let point = post["Location"] as! PFGeoPoint
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
            annotation.title = post["title"] as! String!
            annotation.subtitle = post["username"] as! String!


            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Here is a photo of my Parse backend to give you a better idea:

http://i1249.photobucket.com/albums/hh512/zachkhan3/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-24%20at%205.39.18%20PM.png

Comment: You need to retrieve "createadAt" field and use NSDateFormatter to format it.

Comment: Thanks Teddy! I will try to mess around with it and let you know if it works out.

Comment: When I retrieve "createdAt", do I store it as a String?

Comment: No-no. Just use this: let createdAt = post.createdAt. CreatedAt is not a "real field" but a property of the object itself. And it returns an NSDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFObject has a "CreatedAt" property. You assign it to an NSDate object and you need to format it using NSDateFormatter to display the time component only. Untested code for you.

```
       for post in myPosts {
        let point = post["Location"] as! PFGeoPoint
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
        annotation.title = post["title"] as! String!
        annotation.subtitle = post["username"] as! String!
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle

        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt)
        annotation.timeTitle /* or something equivalent */ = dateString

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```